# Installing NodeJS on Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I need to install version [12 of NodeJS](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories/) on Ubuntu but looks like my company is for some reason blocking the path to the files. When I run the `curl -L https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -`command I get a `curl: (7) Failed to connect to deb.nodesource.com port 443: Connection refused` error message.

How can I install node manually on Ubuntu Trusty? I assume the option I have is to somehow get the setup files on the server, add it to the repository and then run the `sudo apt-get install nodejs` command ,but I'm really not for certain.

FYI: They've also blocked the `git` protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS really shouldn't be blocked - it may be another network issue (with DNS or certificates etc). Anyway, you could try different commands:

- Use HTTP instead:

  ```
  curl -L http://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
  ```
- Use `wget` (or another downloader) instead, and execute it:

  ```
  wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12
  sudo bash ./setup_0.12
  ```

All `curl -L https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -` should do is download the script and run it as root, so it can be done in other ways. However it may be a good idea to talk to the people who run the setup if HTTPS is blocked/scanned  - as generally doing that makes things insecure.

You can install `nodejs` from the Ubuntu repos (with `apt-get` etc), but it may be a older version (see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&searchon=names&keywords=nodejs))

Comment: It's actually being blocked by my company but using wget gave me a better error message on how to proceed.